# "fatal unable access [path] Failed connect gihub.com port 443 Connection refused" Trying to connect github repository - NOT using a proxy

Tags: git, github, connection

I am trying to connect my first git repository to github.

I followed the commands given from within my repository:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/[username]/git_practice.git  
git push -u origin master
```

... and got the following error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://gihub.com/[username]/git_practice.git/': Failed to connect to gihub.com port 443: Connection refused
```

I searched around, but it seems every other solution is just about modifying the git config file to account for a proxy.  However, I verified that I am not behind a proxy.

What else might be causing this error, and how can I solve this issue?

P.S.  This error showed up a minute or two after issuing the command, but without prompting for username/password.

P.P.S. In case it's helpful, here are the contents of my git config file:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://gihub.com/acalvino4/git_practice.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: Just a typo ... I know it happens to all of us...
But I'm not sure now if this question is even worth keeping up here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, turns out I just had a typo in the remote origin url ('gihub' vs 'github').
Fixing that fixed the issue.

Comment: Glad you found the fix. You should be able to accept your own answer soon, or you can delete the question.